# Mongo query takes 76 seconds in production but not using Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I have a query:

`db.content.find({ "$or" : [ { "cik" : "0000764839"} , { "entitiesDetected.ids" : "ZqH9BvtitcYR88NKC"}], "pubDate" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : -2206281600000}}, "orderBy": {"pubDate": -1, "title": 1}}).explain()`

In production this takes 76 seconds to return the data to the client, according to the MMS profile.

But when I run the same query in the Mongo shell, I get nscanned of 12, and it's super fast - 7 ms.

So what could be wrong?  I asked the MMS people if there was something obvious in my MMS profile, and they didn't seem to think that anything was obviously wrong.  I'm stumped at this point.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Linode 2048 (two cores - 2GB ram).

Comment: So you're running the same query in your application and in the mongo shell, and yet the application takes 76 seconds to return a result, but the shell takes less than one second? You need to supply the lines in your log files that represent the query submitted by your application and then the query submitted by the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your driver is likely adding implied sorting orders that are stepping outside of indexes, especially if you're using compound indexes on any of those fields. You need to run an `.explain()` in your application's query and then on the mongo shell query and compare the outputs of the two. You should also compare the log line that is recorded when the application makes the query versus when the shell makes the query. Make note of any indexes, especially including compound indexes, and their sorting order compared to the query's sorting order.